# How does parent of custom exception class get the arguments if I don't call super().__init__()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose I create a custom exception class like this:

```
class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        pass

raise MyError('this is an error')

# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
# __main__.MyError: this is an error
```

The `MyError` class doesn't call `super().__init__()`, so I don't see any way for the parent class to learn the error message (`'this is an error'`). Nevertheless, this code works correctly: the error message is indeed stored somewhere in the object and printed when I raise the exception.

How and why is this done? I would expect the parent class to know nothing about the error message if I override `__init__()` in the child class and don't call `super().__init__()`. I tried to find Python code for the Exception class, but it looks like it's [in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/exceptions.c) and I was reluctant to dive in and figure it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's kind of weird. `BaseException` implements both [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) *and* [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__), and sets `self.args` in *both* methods. Most classes only implement one or the other. You only overrode `__init__`, so `__new__` still receives the arguments.

If you overrode `__new__` and prevented the arguments from reaching `BaseException.__new__`, you'd find the message is lost:

```
class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        pass
    def __new__(cls, msg):
        return super().__new__(cls)
```

Comment: Thanks! I never knew about `__new__()`. Now it makes sense and I learned something new today. So when you call `MyError('msg')`, it actually calls `MyError.__new__(MyError, 'msg')`, then `__new__` constructs the object (maybe with `super().__new__(cls)`), and has a chance to modify it before returning it. Then Python calls `__init__()` on the returned object, and finally returns the object as the result of calling `MyError('msg')`.